# Get Future Call Stack in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

To elaborate more on the question, I would like to know what are the calls in the call stack( to handle it programmatically ) which are going to be executed, something similar to how we debug in developer options using F10 where the javascript engine knows which are the calls that are going to get executed. I would like to read the future call stack in code.

```
function a() { f(); b(); }
function b() { c(); }
function c() { d(); }
function d() { ...  }
function f() { // identify which are the calls that are pending in the call stack.  }
```

In the above example, I want to know in function f , that the function calls b,c and d are still pending in the call stack.

Comment: it's not very clear what's your goal here

Comment: This sounds a **lot** like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's your real goal?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  The goal is that I want a code to be executed in function f only when the final function d is executed.

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari: You'll have to have `f` return a function that gets passed along the chain to `d`, which calls it. Again, a *real* example would let people help you better, but that would probably be for a different question at this point. The answer to the question above is "you can't do that." :-)

Comment: The "call stack" is a stack of *previous* calls, not *future* calls.  The code doesn't know what it's *going* to do until it does it, but it does no where it came from and that information is recorded in the `call stack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such stack (outside of the branch predictor pipeline in the CPU, which is very small and not accessible). Separately: It would be an ***amazingly*** bad idea to make that information available, not least because — as with all forms of time travel — you have the paradox that if `f` knows what's coming next, `f` could do something to change that.

Answer (score 0):

If you had provided us with a more practical example, we would most likely recommend you deferred objects/promisses. With those you can register functions in a chain and get notified on when for example all have finished.